# Как точно также спозиционировать текст с помощью bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как точно также как на скриншоте задать расположение текста? Используется сетка bootstrap. Шрифты подключаются к словам без проблем. Но такое расположение никак не удается, особенно слово "CREATIVE".[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы уверены, что имеет смысл возиться с текстом? Обычно делают что-то типа`<img src="logo.png" alt="Think let out the creative beast">`. Читалки и поисковики смогут прочесть текст из атрибута `alt`, а юзеры получат красивое лого - без тонны подгружающихся лишних шрифтов. Это если говорить о том, как правильнее.

Comment: Используйте для выравнивания свойство Line-height.

Comment: @terron только поправка - лучше все же svg чем png для таких вещей. А то на ретине оквадратится...

Comment: @Vadizar Никакой конкретики — просто используйте свойство. Вы можете более развёрнуто: с примерами и пояснениями?